# Examples of fonts where some letters are very different from normal

Tags: typography

Most fonts are slight (yet visually distinct somehow) variations on the same overall shape. For example, the letter [k](https://www.pinterest.com/letterkit/k/) is pretty much just that, a `|` with a `<` or something close to it. (Ignoring cursive for this post).

But I wonder what some example fonts are (or how to search for them generally) that diverge on some letters _significantly. For example, the letter `i` always has the dot on top for the most part, but you could also do dotless `i`, `ı`, or could go further and even try out something like `ʌ` for `i`. You wouldn't want to use `:` for `i` because it's already an existing common symbol. But perhaps you could try out some [other ones](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/So): `↿` or `⌔`, or even just `□`.

So then you would have:

```
abcdefghʌj⍧lmnop⌕rstuvwxyz
```

You don't want to go so far and just make them arbitrary like this:

```
©௸࿌...
(a b c ...)
```

You would still have them *close* to the original, but just go out a little further than normal.

I'm wondering if there are any *popular* examples of this with a *readable* font.

Comment: Kind of broad question, about 70% of the typographies designed have their own formal personality among their characters, simply open a font catalog and see.

Comment: people do this kind of thing all the time, anywhere they think it's 'fun' to play with unicode, by swapping in characters meant to look like english letters. It's usually as irritating as all heck. Examples I have ready prepared which I use to point this out to people... `đʘɳʽɫ ɷɌȋɬɚ Ļıƙɚ ɫɧıș,  ıɬʽƨ ǚȵɍɛąδąϐĻϧ ` or `ⓘṨℒ⒴ Ṉẳℳℯ Ⓓʳⁱᵛᵉ Ⓜᵉ ÇℜẰ `

Comment: Problem with dotless "i" is that there are countries where dotted and dotless is a different letter. (Turkey i am looking at you). @Tetsujin ¡ǝʇɐɯ ollǝH

Comment: I don't mean this post to be about unicode specifically, I was just using that as a quick hack to drawing a character out of ordinary. I was more wondering just purely from a drawing perspective fonts that have very different representations of standard characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of fonts on dafont that might suit your purposes

[Hacker Argot](https://www.dafont.com/hacker-argot.font)

[image]

And [X-Cryption](https://www.dafont.com/x-cryption.font)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my font library every small-case i has a dot, but here are some workarounds for individual characters. Use a capital i (I) then select it and change the size and the font. Try a forward or back slash, etc, in the different fonts. My comment in your 'at' question tells how to quickly view all the font variations. Build up your library of distinctive fonts, even free ones, so you have a large repertoire to work from.